# Custom date in MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB stores created timestamp in primary key field _id ObjectId. This field is indexed.

I need to store and filter documents by date (not created date) and I would like take advantage of this field.

How can I generate unique ObjectIds with my custom date? Should I do it? Or should I just create another field for my date and index it.

Comment: probably you can create you custom primary key, which in turn will be a combination of your primary key + current date (or which ever date you require). Then you can break your primary key and take advantage of this field.

Comment: Regardless of what you want to store, it is still the `_id` and therefore the Primary key. So it is immutable and you cannot change it, therefore "creation date" is really a logical choice, unless you have some other "one off" date in mind. If this is a property you expect to change, then you are better off just defining another property in your document instead.

Comment: _id with my custom date wouldnt change after creating. There are more questions under Robin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB auto generates ObjectId and populates it in **_id** field of document upon creation of new document.

According to MongoDB documentation

**An ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type having the following structure**:

The first 4 bytes representing the seconds since the unix epoch

The next 3 bytes are the machine identifier

The next 2 bytes consists of process id

The last 3 bytes are a random counter value

Following is code snippet for generation of ObjectId

```
Object_id = ObjectId()
```

We can also specify 12 byte custom id for generation of ObjectId

```
 Object_id = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4")
```

Comment: Ok, so there are two ways. 1) Generate default mongodb objectid with creation timestamp and then edit the first four bytes. Would it still be unique if there were a lot of objectids with same first four bytes? 2) Generate my own objectid. But I don't know how to generate those 8 last bytes. Which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

For the people looking to create a new mongo objectId for a custom timestamp, use the following for mongoose library

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


let anyTimeInMillisecs = Date.now();
var thisTimeStamp = Math.floor(anyTimeInMillisecs / 1000);
var newObjId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(thisTimeStamp); //our custom object ID
```